# Randomly change the backcolor of selected dates in calendar asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012

Using calendar control in Visual Studio for the web 2012, I am able to take dates from the SQL Server 2012 database (i.e **to date** and **from date** and highlight this dates in the calendar) I am also able to highlight the dates in-between the **to date** and **from date**.

All in all in my calendar at the moment I have dates 02/10/2013 (to date) and 04/10/2013 (from date) highlighted in the calendar and the dates in-between these dates. And also 15/10/2013 (to date) and 19/10/2013 (from date) highlighted and the dates in-between these dates are highlighted.

*However I want to be able to randomly change the back colour of each of the selected date blocks in the calendar? How do I do this?*

Many thanks

here is bit of the code that highlights the dates with a back color and makes them selectable and such. This code works perfectly fine but I want to be able to do the above?

```
                 protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
                 {
    if (dsHolidays != null)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in dsHolidays.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            DateTime nextDate;
            DateTime endDate;
            nextDate = (DateTime)dr["date"];
            endDate = (DateTime)dr["date1"];
            if (nextDate <= e.Day.Date && endDate >= e.Day.Date)             
            {
                e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;

                // dates are unselectable
                e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
            }
        }
    }
    // makes the all the first dates selectable 
    foreach (DataRow dr in dsHolidays.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        DateTime nextDate1;
        nextDate1 = (DateTime)dr["date"];
        {
            if (e.Day.Date == nextDate1)
            {
                e.Day.IsSelectable = true;
                e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code can help

```
Random randomGen = new Random();
KnownColor[] names = (KnownColor[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor));
Color newColor = Color.FromKnownColor(names[randomGen.Next(names.Length)]);
```

Comment: How would I add this code using the code above, that I have added.       thannks

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Day.IsWeekend)
    {
        e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
    }

    if(e.Day.Date.Day%2==0 && !e.Day.IsOtherMonth && !e.Day.IsWeekend)
    {
        e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
        e.Cell.ToolTip = "Booked";

    }
    if (e.Day.Date.Day % 2 != 0 && !e.Day.IsOtherMonth && !e.Day.IsWeekend)
    {
        e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.PaleGreen;
        e.Cell.ToolTip = "Available";
    }
    if(e.Day.Date.Day%5==0 && !e.Day.IsOtherMonth && !e.Day.IsWeekend )
    {
        e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        e.Cell.ToolTip = "Fast Booking";
    }
}
```